# How to get the Row Count of a specific column in UFT API

Tags: c#, excel, hp-uft, uft-api

I am using custom code in UFT API and need to get the row count of specific column.

**A B**

1 1

2 2

3 3

4

it can have different row count for each column and at a time i just need to read one column.

```
 var createlist = new List<string>();
 int rowno =GetDataSource("TACheck!Sheet1").RowsCount;
 for(int i=1;i<rowno;i++)
 {
   String val = GetDataSource("TACheck!Sheet1").GetValue(i,"A").ToString();
   createlist.Add(val);
 }
```

Comment: so for column A, the answer would be 4, and for B 3 ? in your example ?

Comment: yes, the count for A:4 and for B:3